# How to effectively fire a contractor and avoid liens or other legal issues

Tags: contractors

There may come a time despite all the research, when you realize the contractor you hired just isn't up to snuff. what is the best way to fire them and avoid liens or legal battles?

Is this something that should be discussed while creating the contract, or is it just a down side of working with bad contractors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned perhaps you could draw up a fairly tight contract which included quality metrics and a schedule of work.

Then if things aren't up to standard you could terminate due to breach of contract.

The big drawback with this is getting someone to sign up to such a document in the first place.

Comment: +1 for having a clear contract.  Thankfully on the projects I've had a contractor involved in, the contract explicitly defined the acceptable terms of termination and procedure for it too. Knowing this ahead of time makes unfortunate tasks like that a bit easier (for both sides).